# "Splitting" project into independent folders

Tags: svn, version-control

On my earlier projects (school and side projects)  I have mainly used one language per project and on my local machine I have a folder structure for my source code similar to

```
/home/me/coding
|
|____ c
|     |___ project(c,1)
|     |___ project(c,2)
|
|____ haskell
|     |___ project(haskell,1)
|
|____ java
      |___ project(java,1)
      |___ project(java,2)
      |___ project(java,3)
```

I use SVN for version control and have a repository on my uni's server and then access the repository through svn+ssh.

I am starting on a project initially based on existing code from some of my language folders and would like to keep the source code in different languages in their appropriate folders on my machine but can not work out how to do things with SVN such that I don't have to create and checkout the whole project into the folder of every language used in the project.

So basically I am asking how to, using svn or similarly, have version control of existing source code files in different folders, collectively forming a project, and not having to either have multiple versions of the whole project or creating one individual project per language used (because in that case I can not work out how to effectively version control the project "fused" of the language sub-projects)

Comment: This is a little tricky to understand - you've given an example of your folder structure, can you give an example of what you actually want to checkout?

Comment: Say I have file1.c in /home/me/coding/c and file2.hs in /home/me/coding/haskell and want these two files to become part of a project that I put under version control. I want to be able to work on the two files in their original positions and able to do eg. `svn log` when being in the two respective folders without having to create new folders. But perhaps I misunderstand version control and have to create a separate structure overall for a project. I just want to kind of say to SVN: Tag this file as part of this new project and keep me updated with changes on all files tagged for this project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, what you're talking about are SVN externals: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.externals.html

This will allow you to pull content from multiple different repositories - which is still maintained in those paths - and use them within a new project.